Approximating Distortion Risk Measures by the Sum of their CVaRs
Can you please cite me to the paper that prove the theorem that any distortion risk measure can be approximated using the sum of its CVaRs?
Someone said it is Axiomatic Characterization of Distortion Risk Measures by Wang T (2018). I cant find this paper anywhere.
Thanks.
